# Split cell into five equally sized "sub-cells" with fixed width

Tags: tables, tabularx, cell, cellcolor

I am trying to color cells of a table with 3 rows of 2 cm width each using `tabularx` and `cellcolor`. I want to split an arbitrary number of cells of this table into "sub-cells" with different colors, but I can't get the spacing right even with one split-up cell:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|X|>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X@{}>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X@{}>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X@{}>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X@{}>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X|X|}
  \cellcolor{gray} &
      \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{green} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{orange} & \cellcolor{blue} &
  \cellcolor{gray} \\
  1 & \multicolumn{5}{X|}{2} & 3\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen below, the blue "sub-cell" is far bigger than the red, green, yellow and orange ones, which are too small. In total, the width seems to be o.k., though.

[image: Example with incorrect sizes]

I found some `tikz`-based solutions here, but they use overlays which I am trying to avoid because I will likely be using a large number of tables and "sub-cells" for illustrating a document that I am currently working on. Is there any way to split each cell into "sub-cells" of equal width?

Comment: Why are you using tabularx? It (at least in your example) make things only complicated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: A table would have been fine as well. I just found it more convenient since I could specify a total length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that kind of figure/table I would really consider Tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[gray](0,0) rectangle (15,1.5);
  \foreach \x/\col in {5/red,6/green,7/yellow,8/orange,9/blue}{
    \fill[\col] (\x,0) rectangle +(1,1.5);
  }
  \foreach \x/\label in {0/1,5/2,10/3,15/}{
    \draw[thin] (\x,-1.5) -- +(0,3) node[pos=0.5,anchor=north west]{\Huge\label};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a lot simpler than the other solutions I found on SO. I'll use that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, row and columns.

So, it's possible to add a Tikz picture in a cell by using the nodes created by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
\CodeBefore
  \tikz
    \foreach \x / \col in {0/red,1/green,2/yellow,3/orange,4/blue}
      { \fill [\col] ($(1-|2)!0.2*\x!(1-|3)$) rectangle ($(2-|2)!0.2*\x+0.2!(2-|3)$) ; } ;
\Body
\cellcolor{gray}  &   &\cellcolor{gray}   \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & bla bla bla  & 6 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]